# Javascript closure is not incrementing value

Tags: javascript, lexical-closures

```
function setupCounter(val){
  console.log(val);
    return function counter(){
      console.log('counter func ', val);
        return val++;
      }
    }
debugger
let counter1 = setupCounter(0);
console.log(counter1()); //0
console.log(counter1()); //1
```

Why the first `counter1()` does not increment value and returns 0. But the second call increments the value to 1, as expected: [here is what I've been debuggin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwQ1C.jpg)

Comment: Use `return ++val`

Comment: val++ vs ++val I think is what you are confused about? val++ returns the value first, then increments it - while ++val increments the value first then returns it.
if you are expecting (0) to return with a 1 - then you need to increment it first then return it.

Comment: And ideally you would get 2 in second case, 1 in first case because of closures.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is the postfix increment operator doesn't return what you expect. Quoting from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment:

> If used postfix, with operator after operand (for example, x++), the
> increment operator increments and returns the value before
> incrementing.
>
> If used prefix, with operator before operand (for example, ++x), the
> increment operator increments and returns the value after
> incrementing.

Using `val++` will actually return the *previous* value, rather than what it becomes. If you want it to return the *new* value, you'd use the increment operator as a prefix, like: `++val`.

Because of this common confusion, I prefer to be more verbose and do something like this:

```
val += 1;
return val;
```

Comment: There's nothing implicit about `++val`.